# Printing the output to a file in perl

Tags: regex, perl, file-io, stdout

I have been trying to find examples related to file handling, but I haven't found anything that will solve my problem.

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my ($m, $b)    = @ARGV;
    my $count_args = $#ARGV + 1;
    my $times      = 2**$m;

    my $output = "main fucntion to be called???\n";

    open(OUTFILE, "> output1.txt") || die "could not open output file";

    print OUTFILE "$output\n"; ## Notice, there is not a comma after the file handle and the string to be output

    close(OUTFILE);

    main();

    sub main {
      if ($m =~ /^\d+$/) {
        if ($b =~ /^and$/i) {
          func_and();
        }
        else {
          print " not supported\n";
        }
      }
      else {
        print " enter valid number of pins\n";
      }
    }

    sub func_and {
      my $bit;
      for (my $i = 0 ; $i < $times ; $i++) {
        my $p = sprintf("%0${m}b", $i);
        print "$p\t";
        my @c = split('', $p);
        my $result = 100;
        foreach $bit (@c) {
          if ($result < 100) {
            $result = $result && $bit;
          }
          else {
            $result = $bit;
          }
        }
        print "result is $result \n";
      }
    }
```

This program prints an output if I provide the input as 2 and the output is printed on the screen.

I want to change the file handle `STDOUT` of this program that is i want to print the output to output1.txt file

Can you please point out the mistake I am making?
    ----->

## copy STDOUT to another filehandle

```
open (my $STDOLD, '>&', STDOUT);

# redirect STDOUT to log.txt

open (STDOUT, '>>', "$ARGV[1]".".log");

print main();

# restore STDOUT
open (STDOUT, '>&', $STDOLD);

print " check .log file\n This should show in the terminal\n";
```

This works for me.. but in the end of the log file i have digit "1" printed i don't know    why..I believe it is the timestamp being printed. I need to remove it.. do u know why is it happening?

Comment: There is no need to declare a `main` subroutine. You aren't writing in C

Comment: @borodin I have multiple sub routines being called from the main program, that is why i declared it

Comment: There is no reason to declare a `main` and then call it. You are using your subroutines in an unusual way by declaring a `$times` outside instead of passing it as a parameter.

Comment: @Borodin okay, I will make that correction

Comment: No, please don't change things as it will confuse the problem.

Comment: Please explain what `func_and` is supposed to do so that I can help you?

Comment: @borodin so for the func_and, if the command line has 1 numeric and a word(and) entered, it sets a counter ( limit = 2**number in command line). we convert these decimal number into binary. example 0 = 00, 1 = 01, 2 = 10, 3 =11. then we split these binary number and perform an & opration over them.. like 0 & 1 = 0 and so on. and u diplay this result.

Comment: @Borodin  
# copy STDOUT to another filehandle
open (my $STDOLD, '>&', STDOUT);

# redirect STDOUT to log.txt

open (STDOUT, '>>', "$ARGV[1]".".log");

print main();

close HANDLE;

# restore STDOUT
open (STDOUT, '>&', $STDOLD);

print " check .log file\n This should show in the terminal\n";                works for me.. but in the end of the log file i have digit "1" printed i don't know why.. need to remove it.. do u know why is it happening?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to redirect the output from the program to a file?

To do that from the command line, enter

```
perl myprogram.pl > myoutput.txt
```

---

If you want everything printed to `STDOUT` to go to a file then just open it as a file handle at the start of your program.

Like this

```
open STDOUT, '>', 'myoutput.txt' or die $!;
```

Comment: yes, I am aware about this, but I want it to be automatic so that I don't have to explicitly mention it in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Any file handle you assign to the typeglob `*::STDOUT` will become STDOUT.

```
if ( my $fh = FileHandle->new( ">>$stdout_path" )) {
    *::STDOUT = $fh;
}
```

Although I normally usually only redirect STDERR to STDOUT or a file.

Comment: can you please explain this with an example?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following (avoiding using double quotes plus using a "clear then append" approach:

```
:
:
my $output = "main fucntion to be called???\n"; 

open(OUTFILE, '> output1.txt') || die "could not clear down output file"; 
close OUTFILE;
open(OUTFILE, '>> output1.txt') || die "could not open append output file"; 

print OUTFILE "$output\n"; ## Notice, there is not a comma after the file handle and the string to be output 

close OUTFILE;
:
:
```

No need for braces in the close statement. The first open effectively emptys the file. The second is an open-extend (or append). 
I assume you will then use print OUTFILE ... throughout and move the second close Output; to the end of your script.

OR...

```
:
:
my $output = "main fucntion to be called???\n"; 

open(STDOUT, '> output1.txt') || die "could not clear down output file"; 
close STDOUT;
open(STDOUT, '>> output1.txt') || die "could not open append output file"; 

print "$output\n"; ## Notice, there is not a comma after the file handle and the string to be output 
:
:
close STDOUT;
:
:
```

Pretty sure this works - without need for STDOUT on every print command.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But can you explain me how can we print the output from the screen to the file ?

Comment: Yes, use print OUTFILE ... throughout. I think there is also a way to redirect <STDOUT> but I don't think I've done it in a while. Would have to look it up myself.

Comment: I am still not clear on this. I don't need to print my $output, I actually need to print the output of the whole program. my $ output was just my doubt that wether I should have it in there or not

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, You are trying to send everything you "print" to a file. If that is what you want to do, it is fairly simple.

```
open (OUTPUT, '>output1.txt');
#whatever logic you want to do
print OUTPUT "whatever you want to print","temporary outputs";
#any other logic you have for computing the output
print OUTPUT "output1","output2";
#after completing all print statements, close the file handle
close(OUTPUT);
```

Basically, you need to give your File Handle (in my example OUTPUT) to "print" and then print like you would do normally. For example, if your original line is

```
print "not supported\n";
```

It will become

```
print OUTPUT "not supported\n";
```

Comment: this looks good. but what I am printing currently is direclty by calling the main function. Since, this event is becoming true, I get an extra 1 printed in the output file.. which I want to avoid. So either after I have generated the output, I will have to search the last line of the output and remove that 1 or I simply do not print the main function. What is you suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) to set the default filehandle for print:

```
open(my $OUTFILE, '>', 'output1.txt') || die "could not open output file: $!";
select $OUTFILE;
print $output;
```